# How to stop Graphql + Django-Filters to return All Objects when Filter String is Empty?

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-python, django-filters, vue-apollo

Using:

- Django 3.x [ Django-Filters 2.2.0, graphene-django 2.8.0, graphql-relay 2.0.1 ]
- Vue 2.x [ Vue-Apollo ]

---

I have a simple **`Birds`** Django-Model with Fields like **`name`**, **`habitat`** and applied different Filters on these Fields like `icontains` or `iexact`. My Goal was to apply a simple search field in my Frontend (Vue). So far it works, but whenever this Filter Value is empty or has blanks *(see Example 3)*, Graphql returns all Objects.

My first approach was on the FrontEnd and to use some kind of logic on my input value, like when String is Empty/blank send `isnull=true` . But then i thought that Django should handle this in the first place.
I guess this Issue relates to my **`filters`** *(see Django < relay_schema.py)* or in other words do i have to apply some kind of logic on these Filters?

In the moment i try to customize some `filterset_class` but it feels like this would maybe too much, maybe i missed something? So i ask here if maybe someone has some hints, therefore my question is:

*How to stop Graphql + Django-Filters to return All Objects when Filter String is Empty?*

### GraphiQL IDE

> **Example 1**

---

```
query {birdsNodeFilter (name_Iexact: "finch") {
  edges {
    node {
      id
      name
    }
     }
    }
}
```

Returns

```
{
  "data": {
    "birdsNodeFilter": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "QmlyZHNOb2RlOjE=",
            "name": "Finch",
            "habitat": "Europe"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Fine for me!**

> **Example 2**

---

```
query {birdsNodeFilter (name_Iexact: "Unicorns") {
  edges {
    node {
      id
      name
      habitat
    }
     }
    }
}
```

Returns

```
{
  "data": {
    "birdsNodeFilter": {
      "edges": []
    }
  }
}
```

**No Unicorns there - good**

> **Example 3**

---

```
query {birdsNodeFilter (name_Iexact: "") {
  edges {
    node {
      id
      name
    }
     }
    }
}
```

Return

```
{
  "data": {
    "birdsNodeFilter": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "QmlyZHNOb2RlOjE=",
            "name": "Finch",
            "habitat": "Europe"
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "QmlyZHNOb2RlOjI=",
            "name": "Bald Eagle",
            "habitat": "USA"
          }
        },

<...And so on...>
```

**Not fine for me!**

### Django

> **relay_schema.py**

---

```
class BirdsNode(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Birds
        filter_fields = {
            'id': ['iexact'],
            'name': ['iexact', 'icontains', 'istartswith', 'isnull'],
            'habitat': ['iexact', 'icontains', 'istartswith'],
        }
        interfaces = (relay.Node, )


class BirdQuery(graphene.ObjectType):
    birdConNode = relay.Node.Field(BirdsNode)
    birdsNodeFilter = DjangoFilterConnectionField(BirdsNode)
```

Comment: I agree this behavior is not expected, but a workaround would be simple not allowing to make the search when the input is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my Solution which worked in GraphiQL and in my Frontend VUE.
I added a logic to the `Birds2Query` with  `def resolve_all_birds2` for each Filter (for  testing purpose not on all Filter ) .
Besides that i also added a `ExtendedConnection` for counting.

**Note:** i changed the class names from my former Question.

**Update**: This Solution works on the python side. But the `apollo client` provides also the `Apollo manager`  - also known as `Dollar Apollo` - there you can also use the `this.$apollo.queries.tags.skip` property as an  static or dynamic solution to start and stop queries.

> **relay_schema.py**

```
class ExtendedConnection(Connection):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    total_count = Int()
    edge_count = Int()
    name_check = ""

    def resolve_total_count(root, info, **kwargs):
        return root.length
    def resolve_edge_count(root, info, **kwargs):
        return len(root.edges)

class Birds2Node(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:

        model = Birds
        filter_fields =  {
            'id':  ['exact', 'icontains'],
            'name': ['exact', 'icontains', 'istartswith', 'iendswith'],
        }

        interfaces = (relay.Node, )
        connection_class = ExtendedConnection

class Birds2Query(ObjectType):
    birds2 = relay.Node.Field(Birds2Node)
    all_birds2 = DjangoFilterConnectionField(Birds2Node)


    def resolve_all_birds2(self, info, **kwargs):
        # Filtering for Empty/ Blank Values in Filter.Key.Value before returning queryset
         if 'name__icontains' in kwargs:
            nameIcon = kwargs['name__icontains']
            nameIconBool = bool(nameIcon.strip()) # if blanks turns False           
            if nameIconBool == False: # has blanks         
                return Birds.objects.filter(name=None)
            pass

    
        if 'name__istartswith' in kwargs:           
            nameIsta = kwargs['name__istartswith']
            nameIstaBool = bool(nameIsta.strip()) # if blanks turns False          
            if nameIstaBool == False: # has blanks         
                return Birds.objects.filter(name=None)
            pass
         return
```

> **GraphiQL**
> Blockquote

**Example 1**

```
query {allBirds2 (name_Icontains:""){
  totalCount
    edgeCount
    edges {
      node {
        id
        name
        habitat
      }  
    }
  }
}
```

Stopped to return all Objects while Filter is blank.

```
{
  "data": {
    "allBirds2": {
      "totalCount": 0,
      "edgeCount": 0,
      "edges": []
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Example 2** with blanks and one letter

```
query {allBirds2 (name_Icontains:" f  "){
  totalCount
    edgeCount
    edges {
      node {
        id
        name
        habitat
      }  
    }
  }
}
```

return - exactly what i wanted

```
{
  "data": {
    "allBirds2": {
      "totalCount": 1,
      "edgeCount": 1,
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "QmlyZHMyTm9kZTox",
            "name": "Finch",
            "habitat": "Europe"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```